# не получается установить значение скроллинга в новом окне

Tags: javascript

Создаю новое окно:

```
var openedWindow = window.open("/", "новое окно", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=50,top=50,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,width=250,height=300,menubar=no");
```

а задача, чтоб содержимое окна было смещено по осям на 200px, т.е. заранее прокрученно, пытался так:

```
openedWindow.onload = function() {
openedWindow.scrollTo(200,50);
}
```

не получается.

как это реализовать?

Comment: window.opener - это ссылка на родительское окно. Вам же нужно обращаться через openedWindow к новому окну обращаться.

Comment: не работает
    openedWindow.onload = function() {
    openedWindow.scrollTo(200,50);
    }

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: А почему вы в открываемом окне не напишете свой собственный скрипт?

Comment: я сторонний ресурс открываю

Comment: Вы не сможете управлять сторонним ресурсом со своей стороны. Это против политики безопасности.

Comment: но проскролить его можно ведь, речь же об этом, а управлять и не надо

Comment: Проскролить это как раз поуправлять.

Answer (score 1):

Прокрутить "чужую" страницу в окне не получится. Почитайте [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). К сожалению, там методов для прокрутки нету.